# C++ удаления элементов с динамического массива

Tags: c++, массивы

Создаем динамический массив:

```
Array *arr = new Array[2];
```

После добавим в него два элемента:

```
Array* arr0 = new Array();
Array* arr1 = new Array();
arr[0] = *arr0;
arr[1] = *arr1;
```

В деструкторе класса `Array` я хочу сделать сначала итерацию по всем элементам массива и для каждого отдельно вызвать `delete`, так как все они были созданы с помощью оператора `new`, а только после этого вызвать `delete[] arr`. 
Но такая конструкция не работает:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
   delete *arr[i];
}
```

> Ошибка: отсутствует оператор *, соответствующий этим операндам.

Вопрос: 
Как реализовать удаления указателей из динамического массива?

Comment: `delete arr[i];`?

Comment: `delete arr[i];` нужно

Comment: @gil9red `arr[i]` - **не** указатель, какой уж тут `delete`...

Comment: `delete arr[i]` не работает. там друга ошибка.

Comment: не обратил внимание на разыменование `arr[0] = *arr0;`

Comment: Ничего не понятно. "В деструкторе класса `Array` я хочу сделать сначала итерацию по всем элементам массива...". Какого массива??? Класс `Array` не имеет никакого отношения к массиву `arr`, ничего о нем не знает и, разумеется, никак не может итерировать по его элементам в своем деструкторе. (Не говоря уже о том, что ни о каком `delete` для элементов `arr` речи быть не может).Так о каком массиве идет речь?

Comment: @AnT да, я сделал опечатку в названии класса. Другой класс, содержит в себе этот массив и я его имел ввиду, но в любом случае, я уже понял в чем была ошибка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь

```
arr[0] = *arr0;
arr[1] = *arr1;
```

вы **скопировали** (присвоением) объекты. При удалении массива *для этих копий* деструкторы будут вызваны автоматически. А чтоб удалить исходные объекты -

```
delete arr0;
delete arr1;
```

к вашим услугам...

Вот если бы вы делали

```
Array ** arr = new Array*[2];

Array* arr0 = new Array();
Array* arr1 = new Array();
arr[0] = arr0;
arr[1] = arr1;
```

тогда дело другое, тогда перед удалением массива надо было бы выполнить

```
delete a[0];
delete a[1];
```

Comment: Я понял, спасибо. 
Получается, если бы я хотел, чтобы оно работало, как я написал, то надо перегрузить оператор `=`? 
Я просто не хотел, отдельно писать delete для каждого созданного объекта. Думал, может это можно сделать как-то в цикле.

Comment: Ну тогда, как я написал в "Вот если бы" - делайте массив не объектов, а указателей. И переписывать оператор присвоения нужно только если поверхностное копирование (которое по умолчанию) не годится. Ну не получится переписать так, чтоб ваш исходный код заработал - потому что вы храните объекты. Даже если напишете перемещение - все равно удалять выделенную память придется. Извращение типа хранить в скопированном объекте адрес исходного и при удалении удалять и его - не рассматриваю :)

Comment: Вроде как понял, но не точно, но основную ошибку точно понял)) еще раз спасибо. 
Сделал через массив указателей, так работает.

Comment: получается, когда я делаю `arr[0] = *arr1`, то происходит копирование, а значит объект который уже будет лежать в массиве под индексом `arr[0]` фактически будет находиться не в хипе, а в стеке и по этому вызов `delete` для него не работает?

Comment: Он будет находиться в хипе - но в том месте, которое выделено не `Array* arr0 = new Array();`, а `Array *arr = new Array[2];` Когда вы будете удалять `delete[]arr`, будут вызваны деструкторы для всех элементов массива, так что отдельно удалять ничего не нужно.